# SharePoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-addin

I am currently building a SharePoint info-path form with the following business cases below:

1. An overtime form which has two conditions : Emergency and Planned. If Planned, the value of the total hours worked** should not increase until it has been approved by the Line Manager.

Currently the infopath form returns a number and decimal numbers when i return the total hours worked, how can i remove those decimals numbers?

Lastly, If i want the line manager to sign the infopath form when approving, how can i build the electronic signature in SharePoint?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the column format on the list settings to specify the decimal places you'd like.

Comment: basically on the infopath, i am displaying the Total Hours worked which must be a number excluding decimal placed. Under View the number is displayed corrently  but on the infopath form it has decimal numbers. e.g 8.00000000

Comment: I have hours to be worked, hours already worked and total accumulated hours. When an employee select Planned, i do not want the Hours to be worked field updating the Total accumulated hours before the manager approve it.

Comment: Hi Graham, The link above is broken.

Comment: Specific to the issue with the adding values based on a specific factor, you can use a [calculated column](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx)